# MongoDB - Find document in which array contains any items in query array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have Schema

```js
person = {
 skill = [{
        type: String
    }]
 name = { type : String}
}
```

I have a `skill` array

```js
skill = ['python', 'css']
```

I want all the people that match at least one skill from the skill array.

`$all` and `$in` retrieve only people that match all the skills in the `skill` array but I want the people that match at least one skill from the `skill` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/).

1. `$setIntersection` - Intersect the input skill array with `skill` field and returns a array with common (intersect) value(s).
2. `$ne` - Filter the document with result from (1) is not empty array.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      {
        $setIntersection: [
          [
            "python",
            "css"
          ],
          "$skill"
        ]
      },
      []
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nVTJH1A66RE)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"$in"` for your purpose.  Perhaps you had some other issue when you tried it before.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "skill": {
    "$in": [ "python", "css" ]
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7sfGuItQ5K-).

Just for fun, here's another [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZJNajVbGICh) example that uses a [mgodatagen](https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen) configuration to generate the collection. The query is the same.